# Webchat in asp.net web-application with XMPP stanards

Tags: asp.net, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I have developed a web-application using ASP.net also deployed the website on windows web hosting provider.

Now I wish to add chat facility to it with XMPP standards. I searched , found many things and eventually got confused totally.

I came across ejabberd server, the best in business. But I have no clear idea how to make use of it in this scenario.

even came to know about libraries, like Matrix , but confused how could I use it.

Kindly explain me these concepts and make me understand the solution in this scenario.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

XMPP need always a server clients connect to. ejabberd is such a server. You can find many other servers here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

MatriX is a XMPP library for .NET. You can find many other XMPP libraries here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/

asp.net does not give you any advantages if it comes to XMPP development, because its a server side language. But you should better keep the load on the client. The best solution is a client side Java Script library with BOSH like Strophe. I suggest to read the following book: http://professionalxmpp.com/

If you want to stay with .Net then Silverlight is an option.